# Google Calendar API SendNotifications = true; Spam Protection

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-developer-tools

my code for creating events, sharing them with others and sending invites/notifications works perfectly.

But what if my code gets somehow stuck in a loop and creating events repeatedly? May I wake up some day with thousands of invites in my mailbox?
Is there something like a spam-protection? :D

Didn't found anything about that in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Calendar API does not cover anti spamming.
In order to prevent spamming, [Google Calendar limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en) the number of invitations a user can send to external guests. This limit varies depending on the action and is usually between 100-300 guests.